# How to enable SQL output to log file with Zend_Db?

Tags: zend-framework, logging, zend-db

I wonder if this possible with Zend_Db, but I am looking for something like SQL query logging similar to how Hibernate does it, where it shows you what SQL it generates in the log file.

Comment: Take a look at this answer if you are looking for an option to write the profiler output to a log file:
  [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114988/zend-enable-sql-query-logging/8119913#8119913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Zend_Db_Profiler for this task.

[Tutorial Zend Framework 1.6 with Profiler and FireBug](http://www.christophdorn.com/Blog/2008/09/02/firephp-and-zend-framework-16/)

Comment: Link is dead now. This is why adding information to answer makes SO better.

Comment: Added new link, you are right but currently not enough time