# Zend Enable SQL Query logging

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am using this to retrieve the database connection atm.

```
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

I do set this up in my config like this:

```
resources.db.adapter = pdo_mysql
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = password
resources.db.params.dbname = db
resources.db.params.profiler.enabled = true
resources.db.params.profiler.class = Zend_Db_Profiler
```

I would like to output everything to a sql.log for example. Is this possible to apply on the default adapter? for example through the settings, so I can ignore it in production environment?

Much appriciated.

I did look at: [How to enable SQL output to log file with Zend_Db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894077/how-to-enable-sql-output-to-log-file-with-zend-db) but it didn't seem to cover my issue.

/Marcus

Answer (score 13):

There is an example of extending Zend_Db_Profiler so you can write the queries to /logs/db-queries.log  file.

So you have to do the following:

1. Create My_Db_Profiler_Log class in the library folder
2. Add the following lines to the application.ini

resources.db.params.profiler.enabled = true

resources.db.params.profiler.class = My_Db_Profiler_Log

Note: be aware, that the log file will become very big, very soon! So it is a good idea to log only the queries you are interested in. And this example should be considered only as a starting point in implementation of such a logging system.

Here is the code for the custom profiler class:

```
<?php

class My_Db_Profiler_Log extends Zend_Db_Profiler {

/**
 * Zend_Log instance
 * @var Zend_Log
 */
protected $_log;

/**
 * counter of the total elapsed time
 * @var double 
 */
protected $_totalElapsedTime;


public function __construct($enabled = false) {
    parent::__construct($enabled);

    $this->_log = new Zend_Log();
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(APPLICATION_PATH . '/logs/db-queries.log');
    $this->_log->addWriter($writer);
}

/**
 * Intercept the query end and log the profiling data.
 *
 * @param  integer $queryId
 * @throws Zend_Db_Profiler_Exception
 * @return void
 */
public function queryEnd($queryId) {
    $state = parent::queryEnd($queryId);

    if (!$this->getEnabled() || $state == self::IGNORED) {
        return;
    }

    // get profile of the current query
    $profile = $this->getQueryProfile($queryId);



        // update totalElapsedTime counter
        $this->_totalElapsedTime += $profile->getElapsedSecs();

        // create the message to be logged
        $message = "\r\nElapsed Secs: " . round($profile->getElapsedSecs(), 5) . "\r\n";
        $message .= "Query: " . $profile->getQuery() . "\r\n";

        // log the message as INFO message
        $this->_log->info($message);

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Extend the Zend_Db_Profiler to write to an SQL.log and attach the profiler to your db adapter

```
<?php

class File_Profiler extends Zend_Db_Profiler {
 /**
  * The filename to save the queries
  *
  * @var string
  */
 protected $_filename;

 /**
  * The file handle
  *
  * @var resource
  */
  protected $_handle = null;

 /**
  * Class constructor
  *
  * @param string $filename
  */
 public function __construct( $filename ) {
   $this->_filename = $filename;
 }

 /**
  * Change the profiler status. If the profiler is not enabled no
  * query will be written to the destination file
  *
  * @param boolean $enabled
  */
 public function setEnabled( $enabled ) {
   parent::setEnabled($enabled);

   if( $this->getEnabled() ) {
     if( !$this->_handle ) {
       if( !($this->_handle = @fopen($this->_filename, "a")) ) {
         throw new Exception("Unable to open filename {$this->_filename} for query profiling");
       }
     }
   }
   else {
     if( $this->_handle ) {
       @fclose($this->_handle);
     }
   }
 }

 /**
  * Intercept parent::queryEnd to catch the query and write it to a file
  *
  * @param int $queryId
  */
 public function queryEnd($queryId) {
   $state = parent::queryEnd($queryId);

   if(!$this->getEnabled() || $state == self::IGNORED) {
     return;
   }

   $profile = $this->getQueryProfile($queryId);

   @fwrite($this->_handle, round($profile->getElapsedSecs(),5) . " " . $profile->getQuery() . " " . ($params=$profile->getQueryParams())?$params:null);
 }
}
```

Haven't test it, but it should do the trick. Give it a try and let me know.

Btw you do know that you can log all queries on the mysql as well?

Comment: Could you explore that a bit please?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

this will let you see sql queries to the web page   , **IT MIGHT BE OFF TOPIC**  but it helpful

I am highly recommend you to use ZF debug bar , it will give you  very handy information 
i am using it to see my doctrine queries , and it had support for `zend db` too

https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug