# Zend_Db_Profiler log to file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-profiler

Is there a simple way to log to queries to a file? I have Firebug profiling working no problem with:

```
resources.db.params.profiler.enabled = "true"
resources.db.params.profiler.class = "Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug"
```

It would be nice to log this to a file with out writing a bunch of code.

Is there a class I can swap out with Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug?

UPDATE: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of ZF 1.11.11 there is no built in profiler class that will log queries to a file.  Currently, FireBug is the only specialized Db Profiler.

Here are two ways in which you can solve it without loads of extra code though.

First, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119913/892493) as it shows how to extend `Zend_Db_Profiler` to have it log the queries to a file on `queryEnd`.  If it doesn't quite do what you want, you can extend `Zend_Db_Profiler` and use the provided code as a starting point.

This next example is a slight modification of a plugin I have in some of my applications that I use to profile queries when the application is in development.  This method utilizes a `dispatchLoopShutdown()` plugin to get an instance of the Db Profiler and log the queries to a file.

```
<?php   /* library/My/Page/DbLogger.php */
class My_Page_DbLogger extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
   public function dispatchLoopShutdown()
   {
       $db        = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('db');
       $profiler  = $db->getProfiler();

       if ($profiler === NULL || !($profiler instanceof Zend_Db_Profiler))
           return;

       // either create your logger here based on config in application.ini
       // or create it elsewhere and store it in the registry
       $logger = Zend_Registry::get('dblog');

       $totalQueries = $profiler->getTotalNumQueries();
       $queryTime    = $profiler->getTotalElapsedSecs();

       $longestTime  = 0;
       $queries      = $profiler->getQueryProfiles();

       if ($queries !== false) {
           $content = "\nExecuted $totalQueries database queries in $queryTime seconds<br />\n";

           foreach ($queries as $query) {
               // TODO: You could use custom logic here to log only selected queries

               $content .= "Query (" . $query->getElapsedSecs() . "s): " . $query->getQuery() . "\n";
               if ($query->getElapsedSecs() > $longestTime) {
                   $longestTime  = $query->getElapsedSecs();
               }
           }

           $content .= "Longest query time: $longestTime.\n" . str_repeat('-', 80);

           $logger->info($content);
       }
   }
}
```

To activate this plugin, you can use code like this in your bootstrap:

```
/**
 * Register the profiler if we are running in a non-production mode
 */
protected function _initPageProfiler()
{
    if (APPLICATION_ENV == 'development') {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new My_Page_DbLogger());
    }
}
```

Ideally, in the long term, you would probably want to make a class that extends `Zend_Db_Profiler` and allow additional options to be specified in your config such as the log file path, the log priority.  This way you can leverage the existing filters to `Zend_Db_Profiler`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and you lead me down the path I was looking for... It is disappointing ZendFramework does not have something like this built in.  I give you credit for your answer, and I will post my answer because it was exactly what I was looking for.