# How to turn on logging (profiling) using ZF2 Doctrine MongoDb module

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

I've successfully integrated Doctrine MongoDB module in Zend Framework 2 and now I need to keep track of each query to MongoDB.
Does anybody know how to turn on logging?

Comment: Are you asking [how to turn on the db profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894077/how-to-enable-sql-output-to-log-file-with-zend-db)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just proposed a [pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule/pull/51) on the [DoctrineMongoODMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoODMModule) to integrate the [logging configuration option](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/logging.html) of MongoDB ODM. Hopefully it'll be merged soon.

You will then only have to add this in the `doctrine-mongo-odm.global.php` file :

```
'doctrine' => array(
    // [...]
    'configuration' => array(
        'odm_default' => array(
            // [...]
            'logger_callable'    => function(array $log, \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) {
               print_r($log);
            }
        )
    )
)
```

The logger_callable will be called for everything there is to log.

Answer (score 0):

You can log each query using the [MongoDB Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-EnablingProfiling).  Use profile level 2.  All queries will be logged to the `system.profile` collection.

Comment: thank's a lot for your answer. But it would be better if I can print all queries directly on current web page or something like this.

Comment: That's sort of true; you're requesting functionality that seems very MongoDB specific and maybe outside the scope of Doctrine, an object mapper.